# Java Constructor date set

Tags: java, date

how to set DATE using constructor?

```
    public Date(int day, int month, int year) 
   {

      this.day=day;         // set day to 1-31
      this.month=month;     // set month to 1-12
      this.year=year;       // set year to 1900-9999

   }
```

if i use

```
if(day<=1 || day >=31)
this.day=day;
else if(month<=1 || month>=12)
this.month=month;
else if(year<=1900 || year>=9999)
this.year=year
```

the problem is if I do this it will only result to 0 however if I removed the conditional statements the day will accept until 32 and months will be accept 13 up and so on

Comment: That is what you are doing right now. Are you facing any problem? If so please [edit] your question and describe it.

Comment: **Why** have you written ***another*** [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class?

Comment: [skorade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9313509/skorade) would like to comment: 

As I understood you are not using any loop, so you don't need if else if conditions. Your if conditions should be independent and separate for day, month and year.

Can you please describe your question a bit more, so that we can get a better picture?

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: @BasilBourque no sir just practicing while im on the christmas break

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Considering the poor design of the `Date` class that you were linking to, there’s every reason to write another one. Fortunately, as the answer says, this has already been done. So I agree with you: there’s no need at all to write a third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create date attributes for holding date information. You can just use either java 8 [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) API . LocalDate is thread safe and immutable, most recommended way of handling date use cases. 
If you insist on creating your own Date class you can just easily do the following.

```
 import java.time.*;

 public class Date {
     final LocalDate date;

     public Date(int day, int month, int year) {

         date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);            
     }

     public int getYear() {
         return date.getYear();
     }

     public Month getMonth() {
         return date.getMonth();
     }

     public int getDay() {
        return date.getDayOfMonth();
     }
 }
```

Using the Date class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{
            Date date1 = new Date(2020, 13, 33);
       } catch(DateTimeException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if Sir I input 31 above on the day and 13 on month and does it return also the same? not an invalid input?

Comment: that will raise java.time.DateTimeException

Comment: I have added exceptions handling  to the code. check  out the updated answer.

Comment: @Solomon don't handle the exception. If you try to construct an invalid date, you shouldn't get a crippled `Date` instance (which yours would be, as `date` would be null): you should throw the exception and thus prevent clients obtaining a useless instance of `Date`. This also isn't thread-safe, because `date` isn't final, so the initialized value is not guaranteed to be visible.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you are right. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you tell me. What do you want to happen? Here are some common options:

1. (recommended): Decree that a given date that clearly cannot exist, is not a legal invocation of the constructor. In other words, `new Date(32, 2, 2051)` isn't valid. To do that, throw an exception. For example:

   ```
   if (day > 31) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Days must be between 1 and 31, inclusive");
   ```
2. Use rollover behaviour, and round off years. This is a 'I don't care it makes no sense do SOMETHING and just don't crash' attitude, and is not recommended. For example, you'd make that date as above act like march 4th, 2051.
3. Something else of your choosing. You are the programmer, after all.

Note that you are reinventing a very common wheel, and thus, unless this is homework or a pure learning exercise ('pure' in the sense of: This code will be tossed in the garbage once you have completed it), it is a mistake. use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead.

NB: Dates are *HARD*. Harder than you think.